# Unable to display welcome message on Skype for Business using Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm trying to display a welcome message anytime someone connects to my bot. This code snippet works on the emulator, and embedded web chat. But it doesn't work on Skype for Business.

```
    bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
        if (message.membersAdded && message.membersAdded.length > 0) {
            bot.send(new builder.Message().address(message.address).text('Hello!'));
        }
    });
```

Does anyone know what part the code is missing? I pulled this snippet from the example code Microsoft Bot Framework has given.

Comment: Skype for Business doesn't send a conversationUpdate event.  I believe it does send a contactRelationUpdate event though.  Please try that for Skype bots.